# Ember simple auth invalidateSession from own controller

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-simple-auth

At the moment i'm facing the problem that I need to use the invalidateSession() action from ember-simple-auth (https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/) in one of my own controllers.

I normally use it like they do in their examples: `{{ action 'invalidateSession' }}` in my handlebars-template. I need to do some `preLogout` stuff before I call `invalidateSession()` so there needs to be a way - but at the moment I can't figure it out how.

Template:

`{{ action 'preLogout' target='view' }}`

View:

```
actions:{
    preLogout:function(){
        this.get("controller").send("preLogout");
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
actions:{
    preLogout: function(){
    var self = this;
    //some preLogout things to do
    //INVALIDATESESSION - how?
    this.transitionToRoute("index");
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do that is to override the `invalidateSession` action and call `_super` after you're don't with the necessary actions, e.g.:

```
// app/routes/applications.js
export default Ember.Route.extend(ApplicationRouteMixin, {
  actions: {
    invalidateSession: function() {
      // do custom stuff…
      this._super();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I will give this a chance - but as it had to be finished very soon I will have to make a little hack at the moment - came up with the idea using a button in the template with this action which won't show up for the user and I will click it with a little nasty helper in the controller. I will come back!